# JSON object recognized as String by jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse some JSON coming from an AJAX request using jQuery.

Basically, the JSON is encoded by PHP and looks like:

```
{"1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},"0":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}
```

The callback function of $.ajax looks like:

```
$.each(data, function(item) {
      console.log($.type(item));
      myfunction(item.key1);
      });
```

item is recognized as a **string** and item.key1 is undefined.

The content-type of the response is "application/json" so jQuery is supposed to parse it. data is then recognized as an object.

So… what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `item` *is* a `String`.

The first argument of the callback of `$.each()` is the key. In your example, your JSON object is an `Object` with numerical indexes, except in strings. You are attempting to access the property from the property name. Instead, you'd want to use `data[item]` in your example.

You want to access the property values like so...

```
$.each(data, function(propertyName, propertyValue) {
      console.log(propertyName, propertyValue);
});
```

Variables names have been changed to be clearer.

In a real `Array`, the arguments would be be the index followed by the value.

Comment: I think you're right. I thought only one argument meant the value, not the key. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the type to json:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: you mean `dataType`, `type` is "GET" or "POST".

Comment: Also, if the mime is `application/json`, jQuery will treat it as JSON I believe.

Comment: I believe dataType isn't needed if you set the correct content-type.

Answer (score 0):

If it is valid JSON it should be ok.

By the looks of the object returned you might have to use:

```
item.1.key1
//Or
item['1'].key1
```

Instead of:

```
item.key1
```

Try that and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

When reviewing the response from the server using Firebug, did you see JSON "tab" for the call? If not, you must add `die();` to the end of the PHP script generating the JSON for jQuery to recognize it as such. Without `die()`, jQuery saw it as a string and I was unable to parse it properly.

I know this question is old, but I hope the answer can help someone else since this problem was a real head-scratcher for me too.